# Inserting printk calls in Linux kernel XHCI driver results in ENOMEM errors?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, out-of-memory, printk

I'm trying to debug a USB problem in an Android application which uses libusb. I'm not sure whether the problem is caused by user code or kernel code. I figured, either way, adding some printk statements to trace the execution path in the relevant portions of the kernel code (XHCI driver) would be helpful.

However, when I boot the newly compiled kernel with the printk statements and insert an OTG cable, the kernel panics because of a NULL pointer dereference which appears to be caused by an `ENOMEM` error in the XHCI code. If I comment out some of the printks, the kernel no longer panics on OTG cable insertion, but it fails to enumerate connected USB devices, again due to an `ENOMEM` error.

How can it be that simply adding a few `printk` statements with string literals (which don't occupy stack memory, right?) could cause `ENOMEM` errors? Is it possible the XHCI code was already dangerously close to filling the 8k stack, and adding the printk calls was just the final straw that broke the camel's back? Or is there a simpler explanation?

Example of the type of `printk` lines I added:

```
printk("BUGHUNT: xhci-mem.c: xhci_urb_enqueue(): ENTER\n");
```

Comment: Try latest kernel. I have heard about something similar in older driver. Also, use trace points instead of heavy `printk()`.

Comment: @0andriy This is for a Nexus 5 phone, so I don't think a kernel newer than `3.4.0` is available.

Comment: No way! It is archaic, nobody will fix plenty of issues there.

Comment: @0andriy Welcome to the world of Android, where devices basically never see a kernel update because of the extent of modification to the kernel (on the order of 30-60k lines in the standard base, **plus** the modification made by OEMs) just renders doing updates very hard.

Comment: Alas, it is way too old. You can look at the changes yourself: _git log --oneline -- drivers/usb/host/xhci*_ to estimate size of disaster.